# Rundeck job notification error (server response: 415 Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: webhooks, rundeck

rundeck ver: 4.0.0

I want to send job execution result to specific webhook url.
So I set job notification use GUI

```
Trigger: On success
Notification Type: Send Webhook
URL(s): specific incoming webhook url
Payload Format: JSON
Method: POST
```

Rundeck job notification error is occured. (server response: 415 Unsupported Media Type)

Is there a configuration file that needs to be added other than the job notifications settings?

Answer (score 0):

To send the job execution result you can use the [HTTP notification plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-notification) and put an export variable (containing the result) in the body section.

For this, you need to "capture" the output and store it on a global variable to put in the notification, I made a workable example that works with [webhooks.site](https://webhook.site) test service:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: bcee72e0-b6fa-4e8e-a065-9937a67f3de7
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  notification:
    onsuccess:
      plugin:
        configuration:
          authentication: None
          body: ${export.myexport}
          contentType: application/json
          method: POST
          remoteUrl: https://webhook.site/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
          timeout: '30000'
        type: HttpNotification
  notifyAvgDurationThreshold: null
  options:
  - name: opt1
    value: localhost
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: nmap ${option.opt1}
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            hideOutput: 'false'
            logData: 'true'
            name: myoutput
            regex: (.*)
          type: key-value-data-multilines
    - description: only for debug
      exec: echo ${data.myoutput}
    - configuration:
        export: myexport
        group: export
        value: ${data.myoutput*}
      nodeStep: false
      type: export-var
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: bcee72e0-b6fa-4e8e-a065-9937a67f3de7
```

1. Run command and [capture the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZNCq.jpg) in a data capture filter, I use the [Multiline Regex Data Capture plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/multiline-regex-datacapture-filter), now the output is saved on a data variable called `${data.myoutput}`.
2. Then using the [Global Variable Workflow Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZNCq.jpg), take the `${data.myoutput}` (using the `${data.myoutput*}` format) and create the `${export.myexport}` variable to use in notifications (just putting the `${export.myexport}` variable).
3. Check the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8hEu.jpg).